# (Very simple) JavaScript error

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code, the commented line of which prevents a JSON to work correctly (when I comment the line, it works; when I uncomment it, it stops working):

```
function GenSpecieChg()
{
var selText = document.getElementById("textGenSpecie");
var sca = selText.value;
//if (sca <> "" && sca.indexOf("%") == -1) selText.value += "%";
localStorage.setItem("34_Delta", selText.value);
alert("GenSpecie changed !");
}
```

What is my error ?

Comment: there is no `<>` in Javascript. Use `!=` instead.

Comment: Including the error message might have also been helpful.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic with reason "This question was caused by ... a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operator in javascript like <> you have to use !=

```
function GenSpecieChg()
{
    var selText = document.getElementById("textGenSpecie");
    var sca = selText.value;
    if (sca != "" && sca.indexOf("%") == -1) selText.value += "%";
    localStorage.setItem("34_Delta", selText.value);
    alert("GenSpecie changed !");
}
```

Comment: And no need to check for empty  value at all, simply use: `sca.indexOf('%') < 0`

Comment: if sca.value is empty then no need to add % sca.value so need to check that value was empty or not along with indexOf

Comment: @The Developer - Yes, exactly. That is what started the whole thing (including this post) - it added an unnecessary % when field was empty. Thanks everybody for their answers to such a pitiful question - I'm new to javascript, but next time I'll check.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing `<>` in JavaScript. Please use `!=`.